# using User.objects.get_or_create() gives invalid password format in django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

```
python manage.py shell

>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u=User.objects.get_or_create(username="testuser2",password="123")
>>> u
(<User: testuser2>, True)
```

seems it created the `User` properly. but when I logged into admin at 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/3/`,
I see this message for password
`Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.`

Screenshot is attached too. why is it this way and how to create `User objects` from shell. I am actually writing a populating script that create mulitple users for my project?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use the [`User.set_password` method to set a raw password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password).

E.g.,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username="testuser2")
user.set_password('123')
user.save()
```

Answer (score 6):

Almost correct except we don't want to set password of existing users

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username="testuser2")
if created:
          # user was created
          # set the password here
          user.set_password('123')
          user.save()
       else:
          # user was retrieved
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#creating-users).

> > The most direct way to create users is to use the included [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) helper function.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(username="testuser2",password="123")
```