# Django doesn't store password field in User model

Tags: python, django, authentication

I created a signup page using Django's builtin signup forms.Here is my code below

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Please provide a valid email address.')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")


        check_email = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if check_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "You are already registered!")
            return cleaned_data

        check_username = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if check_username:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "A user with that username already exists")
            return cleaned_data
```

In my views.py this is how I do the authentication for signup

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            print("signup authencticate", user)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my code to handle user login

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    if request.POST:
        email = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html")   

    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

When I signup, everything seems fine but when I try to login, it just won't let me login.

So when I checked the `django admin`, this is what I found

```
Username: tech1
Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.
Password:
Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.
Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using this form.
```

I don't quite understand why the user password is not stored at the time of signup?

I searched for it and I found out from this answer [using User.objects.get_or_create() gives invalid password format in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924122/using-user-objects-get-or-create-gives-invalid-password-format-in-django) that django encrypts the password before storing and I should use something like

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username="testuser2")
user.set_password('123')
```

But I am not quite sure where to put this in my code or how does this help?What is going on?

Comment: Did you change AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py to point to your new user model?

Comment: @Taylor umm no!How do I do that?

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here basics of how I set up a custom user model:

In Settings.py add:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
```

accounts can be where ever you store you user model.

User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin
)
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import binascii
import os



class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')


        user = self.model.objects.create(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']


    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_superuser
```

I can not recall but I am pretty sure the manager must come first.

Signup

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = "accounts/pre/"
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        valid = super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)
        email, password = form.cleaned_data.get('email'), form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        auth_login(self.request, new_user)
        return valid
```

Forms.py

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "password1", "password2", "first_name", "last_name")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["email"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'})
        self.fields["first_name"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'})
        self.fields["last_name"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'})
        self.fields["password1"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields["password2"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Reenter Password'})
```

Comment: hey sorry I was super busy.Yes it did.Thanks!