# Django user authentication with custom model and mongo db

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm not really experienced in Django and graph databases. But I need to set up user authentication with MongoDB in Django.

I'm using pymongo for connection to database bypassing Django db settings. But I still want to use Django authentication. In order to do so, I actually should create a user model extended from `AbstractBaseUser`, create custom user manager extended from `BaseUserManager`, and register `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.

I've also created and registered custom backend which returns my custom `User` object.

But the problem is that it seems like Django tries to verify my `User` model using its database (sqlite in settings) and it can't find `USERNAME_FIELD` (because actually I'm not using this db. I don't know how to tell Django that it don't need to care about it.

Can you provide any suggestions, please?

Comment: Hi @sharun - hopefully that answer helped. Please up-vote if it's not too much trouble as well. :)

Comment: Hi @MichealJRoberts, I'd like to upvote you, but actually I don't have enough reputation to do it. When I would, I'll surely do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to tell Django to explicitly use MongoDB as it's backend database. There are many tutorials online, however, the best one I can recommend from experience is "[djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/)".

```
(venv) $ pip install djongo && pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you don't have a virtual environment installed, if not just simply use:

```
$ pip install djongo
```

And then in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
   ‘default’: {
      ‘ENGINE’: ‘djongo’,
      ‘NAME’: ‘your-db-name’,
   }
}
```

And that is it! Simple as that, in theory. (Minus any extra database configurations you want to add).

To circumnavigate the `USERNAME_FIELD` issue, simply use something like this in your extended `User` class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager() # <-- THIS IS YOUR CUSTOM USER MANAGER CLASS

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # <-- INCLUDE THIS LINE HERE!
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507794/django-doesnt-store-password-field-in-user-model/51507954#51507954) where I answered a similar question. If you go down to the user class you will `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` Set this to what ever you want to use as the username field. If you are not going to use sqlite and do not need the data delete that file.

If you haven't set up your settings to use mongodb then using djongo is a good choice. just `pip install djongo` and then add

```
DATABASES = {
   ‘default’: {
      ‘ENGINE’: ‘djongo’,
      ‘NAME’: ‘your-db-name’,
   }
}
```

to you settings.py. Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/using-django-with-mongodb-by-adding-just-one-line-of-code-c386a298e179) about djongo